# yii2: Trying to generate model but getting database exception

Tags: mongodb, yii2

I have started working on yii2. I am using mongodb for database. I have generated mongoDbModel using gii interface. Then i moved to model for model generation. When i clicked on model generator it throws me exception

```
Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

My config file code (written mii instead of gii)for gii module is

```
    'modules' => [
    'mii' => [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
        'generators' => [
            'mongoDbModel' => [
                'class' => 'yii\mongodb\gii\model\Generator'
            ],
        'model' => [
                'class' => 'yii\gii\generators\model\Generator'
            ]
        ],
    ],
],
```

when i tried loading with ?r=mii interface is loaded and all functions are working except model generator. How to fix this???

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your database config. I have never used mii but it looks like it tries to use the mysql config to try to read the tables so it fails. Check your config.